# Error while trying to read table from SQL Server with spark

Tags: sql-server, databricks, pyspark

I was trying to read a table from SQL Server installed on my machine. When I try to execute my code, I get an error like this:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host LAPTOP-081IVYQP, port 1433 has failed. Error: "LAPTOP-081IVYQP. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".

This was the code I executed:

```
InputDf= spark.read.format("jdbc")\
.option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://LAPTOP-xxxxx:1433;database=Demoxxxxx")\
.option("dbtable", "dbo.DemoTb")\
.option("user", "xxxxxx")\
.option("password", "xxxxxxxxx")\
.option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")\
.load()
```

Can someone explain and guide me the way to bypass this error and load the table in databricks.